# Is it correct that a node and it's translations have the same node id?

Tags: nodes, 8, i18n-l10n

I just translated a node and I saw that both nodes have the same node id. Since I cant find anything about it: is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's correct because Drupal 8 use [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) (in core) for the translations.

You can more about this in [Drupal 8 multilingual tidbits 17: content translation basics](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2015-jan-27/drupal-8-multilingual-tidbits-17-content-translation-basics)

> If you already built multilingual sites with Drupal 7 that had content
>   translation, you may notice this model is a refined version of [the
>   Drupal 7 Entity translation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) (without awkward modules required
>   like [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title)) rather than the Drupal 7 core content translation module.
>   The core module in Drupal 7 keeps different copies of nodes and
>   relates them together in a translation set. In Drupal 8 this feature
>   is not available, instead you can configure translatability on a field
>   (and in some cases subfield) basis. However if you configure all
>   fields to be fully translatable, you can essentially reproduce the
>   Drupal 7 behavior. Compared to the Drupal 7 core solution with
>   different entity identifiers then, Drupal 8 will have the same entity
>   identifier but a different language variant.
>
> The biggest advantage of the Drupal 8 solution is you can configure to
>   translate as much as needed and not more. With one unified solution to
>   translate only some fields or all fields, (contributed) modules only
>   need to deal with one system instead of two. With storing translations
>   under one entity, modules that don't want or need to deal with
>   multilingual scenarios can still consider the entity as one, no need
>   for special translation set support. That is way more flexible than
>   Drupal 7 and best of all it applies to all kinds of content, not just
>   nodes. It is future proof for modules you enable like rules and
>   commerce.